# Javascript Error when loading items on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having two errors on my site and I think the problem rests in the javascript.  I have firebugs addon that is showing these two errors and the code but I have no idea how to fix it.

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
window.Templates['home'] = _.template('<% if (loggedInUser == null){ %><% } %><div id="home_container">  <div id="home_title">--- is back!</div>  <div id="home_description">Created by music lovers, for music lovers.</div>  <div id="home_header">    <div class="home_header home_header_on"><a href="/explore">Search</a><span> all your favorites</span></div>    <div class="home_header"><a href="#">Share</a><span> songs with friends</span></div>    <div class="home_header"><a href="/trending">See </a> <span>What's </span> <span>Trending</span></div>  </div>  <div id="home_description"> --- is the best way to find and share music online</div>   <div id="home_search_container">    <form id="home_search_form">      <input id="home_search" class="large_input_text" placeholder="Search music" type="text" />      <input id="home_search_button" type="button" value="search" />      <span id="home_search_bg"></span>    </form>  </div>  <div id="home_share" class="hidden">    <div id="home_share_wrapper"> <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="lala" data-related="----:The best place for music on the web">Tweet</a>      <div id="fb-root"></div>      <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="95" data-show-faces="true"></div>      <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>    </div>  </div>  <div class="clear"></div></div><div id="home_footer_container"></div><body background="http://www.----.com/assets/images/testbg.jpg">');
```

The other error is where arrow is pointing
ReferenceError: Templates is not defined

```
var SongView = Backbone.View.extend({
    showAvatar: true,
    user: null,
 ->   template: Templates.common_songs,
    tagName: "div",
    className: "song_row a_song",
    events: {
        "click .song_view_love": "onLovedClicked",
        "click .song_view_share": "onShareClicked",
        "click .song_view_play_button": "onPlayButtonClicked",
        "click .song_view_queue": "onQueueClicked"
    }
```

THIS IS FIXED. However fixing the window.Templates js resulted in new (Type Error: be is undefined) which are shown below. Any ideas?

```
Zc.prototype.Ga=function(a){var b=a[0],c=window;c.google_unique_id?++c.google_unique_id:c.google_unique_id=1;b.cb=c.google_unique_id;this.f.U&&(P(this,"hxva",1),O(this,"cmsid",this.f.H),O(this,"vid",this.f.I));isNaN(this.f.Da)||P(this,"pod",this.f.Da);isNaN(this.f.Ea)||P(this,"ppos",this.f.Ea);isNaN(this.f.r)||P(this,"scor",this.f.r);N.prototype.Ga.call(this,a);a=window;var b=a.document.domain,d=a.document.cookie,e=a.history.length,f=a.screen,g=a.document.referrer,k=Math.round((new Date).getTime()/
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to debug the *actual* page output rather than the server side code?

Comment: how do you go about doing that?

Comment: are you talking about where it says http://----.com/assets/images/testbg.jpg?

Comment: Yes, but see the first answer, it is correct, there is a single quote. The double slashes might be a problem too, but they are after the quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you have a '

```
window.Templates['home'] = _.template('<% i<snip>...span>What's
                                                             ^
```

That is terminating the string inside `_.template('`, remove the ' from What's and try

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly. Nice quick response thanks Adam.  Unfortunately it is resulting in two new errors im uploading them now

Comment: The error you posted says `Type Error: be is undefined` but there is no declaration of `be` in your code but this issue seems different to your original question so it may warrant a new fresh question.

Comment: Hey i just want to let you know I Fixed the problem.  It was a problem with my php files interacting with my javascript. I was being an idiot an adding different languages to certain files. For example regular html or php syntax within javascript or vice versa. just a beginner but thanks for all your help and input

Answer (score 0):

The second error is caused by the first.

If you look at the end of what you posted, the syntax highlighting would have given clue that it is seeing it as a comment because of the "//" in the URL.

```
<body background="http://www.----.com/assets/images/testbg.jpg">');
```

You need to escape the slashes.

Comment: what do you mean escape the slashes?